# What is the meaning of "int *(&arry)[10] = ptrs;"? How do you read something like this?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, declaration

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of arrays. I know

```
int *ptrs[10];
```

has the meaning of ptrs is an array of ten pointers to int. So how about

```
int *(&arry)[10] = ptrs;
```

I'm very confused by its many syntax so could someone please explain it to me what is its meaning and how to read it? It would be great someone can break it down and explain it in smaller parts.

Comment: FWIW, [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*%28%26arry%29%5B10%5D%3B) tells you exactly what `int *(&arry)[10];` is. I've also never personally had a problem following the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), despite some things needing to be grouped and really going back and forth when doing it rather than in a spiral.

Comment: @chris oh wow! I didn't know such useful website exist. Thanks for pointing it out to me, really appreicate it!

Comment: @chris: I wouldn't say it tells you *exactly* what it is. It has its own strange syntax that is not quite English, although it is a little more clear than C and C++ declarations.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Okay, fair point. "array 10 of pointer to int" isn't exactly English. I guess the important part is the ordering.

Comment: "No shame but mine: I must, forsooth, be forced
To give my hand opposed against my heart
Unto a mad-brain rudesby full of spleen;
Who woo'd in haste and means to wed at leisure." Now THAT is English! Say on, William! Pray, spin us a tale!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arry` is a reference (of an array of ten pointers to int). Using `typedef` could make it more clear. They're same as,

```
typedef int* PTRS[10]; 
PTRS& arry = ptrs;
```

or (since c++11)

```
using PTRS = int* [10];
PTRS& arry = ptrs;
```

Comment: Or, in modern C++, `using PTRS = int *[10];`

Answer (score 2):

The variable `arry` is a reference to an array of ten pointers to ints. I have no idea why you'd do this, but that's what it means. :-)